# What Installation is Missing From My VS2015SP3 Install with ASP.NET Core?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I've installed VS2015-sp3 from scratch on an empty win0 computer.  I've gone to the asp.net core download site and installed the latest SDK. I've also gone to the Visual Studio site and installed the latest extension for asp.net core.

What am I missing or forgot?  I'get the error:

```
Unable to starte the process.  No executable found matching command 'dotnet-project-server'
```

[image]

Comment: the latest sdk is not compatible with vs2015, vs 2015 had preview tooling and old project system. latest sdk uses new msbuild.csproj and is only compatible with vs2017. If you must use vs2015 then you need to use an older sdk and you would need a global.json file to declare the specific sdk to use

Comment: if you want to use .NET Core, it's better to go with VS 2017.

Comment: I'm 80% through a pluralsight video course on tag helpers and can't change to 2017 since I've got a ton recorded. What are steps to uninstall and what to reinstall for preview 2 I assume?